# layer to KML conversion

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, kml, convert

I am using arcgis 10.1 and my concern is to convert a layer to KML. The size of the layer that I would like to convert is of 7KB.

For some reason it is being converted all the time with errors. Any suggestions why is this happening?

Comment: what projection is your source data in?

Comment: WGS84 srid 4326

Comment: I had some trouble converting to KML using arcmap. I found QGIS "save as KML" option to be quite handy!

Comment: What is the error you are getting from the Layer To KML tool?

Comment: Actually the kml will be created but then when i go to overlay it on google maps it says that file containing errors. I have already tried it with a smaller scale and it worked fine, so i am presuming that it has to do with size of the data

Comment: Is it a line that you are trying to convert? not a polygon also check how many vertices the object has, I had a line with 40000 vertices which we could convert into a KML file but then wouldn't appear, but the was a 3Mb file (that was our first clue something was wrong)  try dissolving the line/s and if you have Data interoperability extension you can try using that

Comment: What is the exact Google Maps error that you are receiving?

Answer (score 2):

When I use Arcgis "Layer to KML" I always fill blank field "Layer Output Scale", even though it's optional - without that the tool would not work.
[image]

Comment: Yes i filled that option and I made to "1" but still same result.